# Can i reset value of global variable every time i return from a function

Tags: c, function, variables, global

I want a function should reset global variable value to 0 every time its return.

I know I can add `gVar=0;` before every return statement, but this is not the way I want because new developer may not have this information and might not reset `gVar` value.

Requirement is

```
global int gVar = 10;
void fun() 
{
 // Need to modify gVar Here 
  gVar = 15;
  .
  .
  .
  gVar = 20;
  if (some condition)
         return;
  else 
         return; 
..
// more return possible from this function 
// also new developer can add more return statement 
// i want every time function return it should set gVar=0
}
```

Comment: This isn't c or c++. And it doesn't sound like you want to use a global for this purpose.

Comment: Is `global` really part of your code?

Comment: A widely used practive (and one that several static code analysing tools enforce) is to have only one return from any function. If you refactor accordingly, your problem is solved, as far as I understand.

Comment: What language are you using?  C is not C++.

Comment: @Drew That is a valid point. I probably am so used to "do not multi-return" that I lost sight of that.

Comment: This is a old piece of code written in C in my application. I am trying to fix some problem in it.

Comment: I have seen coding styles that have macros like `#define LOCAL` so that `LOCAL` can be used as a tag for code generation and analysis tools. `global` wouldn't be too out of line with that, but I'd expect it to be `GLOBAL`.

Comment: Just don't write code like this, it is very bad design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a class whose destructor sets `gVar` to 0, then declare an instance of it at the start of the function.  When the function returns, the variable goes out of scope and the destructor is called.

```
class ClearGVar {
public:
    ClearGVar() {}
    ~ClearGVar() { gVar = 0; }
}

void fun()
{
    ClearGVar x;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

The C++ tag was removed after this was posted.  There's no good way to do this in C.

Comment: So you assume that OP was not serious when tagging "C", don't you?